# Basic Authorization Angular 5 get Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular5, spring-security-oauth2

I am requesting for an access_token using Basic Authorization in Angular but I get this error.

I tried it in Postman and it has no problem at all.

[image]

I am using a service to post a request from API.

```js
requestToken() {
    var encoded: string = btoa("my-username" + ":" + "my-password")

    let options = {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password',
      grant_type: 'password',
    }

    let _httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    _httpHeader = _httpHeader.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    _httpHeader = _httpHeader.append("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    return this._http.post(API_URL + '/oauth/token?grant_type=' + options.grant_type + '&password=' + options.password + '&username=' + options.username, { headers: _httpHeader, withCredentials: true });
  }
```

Then call that service in my component to save it in session storage.

```js
this._dataService.requestToken()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', res['access_token']);
        sessionStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res['refresh_token']);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
      }
    );
```

Comment: Looking at the Chrome Dev Tools screenshot, the Response does not include the 'Authorization' header in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers. If you have control over the server this is something that you can include to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have control in the server-side. But thanks bro.

Comment: is `API_URL` (triu-svc:8080) a different server address / port to the one serving up the angular app?

Comment: it is the same sir